# Curly brackets c# split issue

Tags: c#

I have data in a string, `email` and `id`, in the format as shown below:

```
string s = "{email:ss@ss.com}{id:AB12345}";
```

I just want to remove curly brackets and extract the email and id from the above string in a variable as below.

```
string email = "ss@ss.com";
string id = "AB12345";
```

I have tried `string.Format` and other formatting. Since email and id size can vary, I can't find a solution.

Comment: I'm going to retag this question as the brackets don't actually make any difference to the problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use can use [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
var match = Regex.Match("{email:ss@ss.com}{id:AB12345}", @"\{email:(.+)\}\{id:(.+)\}");
var email = match.Groups[1].Value;
var id = match.Groups[2].Value;
```

PS:
The pattern `(.+)` means that Email and the Id at least have 1 character, otherwise the match will not find the email and id, if those can be empty you can change it into `(.*)`

Answer (score 4):

Using `Split` you can achieve it like this:

```
var parts = s.Split(new [] { '{', '}' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string email = parts[0].Split(':')[1];
string id = parts[1].Split(':')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex will be nice solution but since I'm not familiar with it, you can use `Substring` and `IndexOf` methods like;

```
string s = "{email:ss@ss.com}{id:AB12345}";
string email = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(':') + 1, 
                           s.IndexOf('}') - s.IndexOf(':') - 1); // ss@ss.com
s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf('}') + 1);
string id = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(':') + 1, 
                        s.IndexOf('}') - s.IndexOf(':') - 1); // AB12345
```

Here a <kbd>[**`demonstration`**](http://ideone.com/aoLfeX)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "{email:ss@ss.com}{id:AB12345}";
string[] str = s.Split("}{".ToArray());
string email = str[1].Replace("email:", "");
string id = str[3].Replace("id:", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  private static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string s = "{email:ss@ss.com}{id:AB12345}";
            string email = string.Empty;
            string id = string.Empty;
            FillValue(s, out email, out id);
            Console.WriteLine("email:{0}\nid:{1}",email,id);
              Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static void FillValue(string s, out string email, out string id)
        {
            var values = s.Replace("}{", "$").Replace("{",string.Empty).Replace("}",string.Empty).Split('$');
            email = values[0].Split(':')[1];
            id = values[1].Split(':')[1];
        }
```